# How do I know if a server has JSONP turned on?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

How do I know if a server has JSONP turned on? It is not my server, but I try to access some information from the rendered html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

For *most* servers, you can make a request in your browser to whatever JSON page/service they have and just add a callback function in the URL, for example if it's this:

```
http://example.com/getJson?var=something
```

Add the `callback` query parameter, like this:

```
http://example.com/getJson?var=something&callback=myFunction
```

The response instead of this (it *will* look like this if it doesn't support JSONP):

```
{ "thing": "value" .... }
```

Should look like this (again, *if* it supports JSONP):

```
myFunction({ "thing": "value" .... });
```

Comment: Right, the operative word there is *most*. :-)

Comment: Should the second url be `http://example.com/getJson?var=something&callback=myFunction` - a & rather than a $

Comment: @Hamish - indeed it should, typo on my part, fixed! and thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The server has JSONP turned on if you can add `callback` to the URL:

```
http://example.com/api/get_info.js?callback=myfunc
```

and the server responds with your requested information in JSON-format, wrapped with your callback:

```
myfunc({
    /* json formatted data goes here */
});
```

Comment: Actually, no. This will only work if the server is looking for `callback` being the callback parameter. The callback parameter can actually be anything.

Comment: The standard is `callback`. For instance, it's what will work with the JSONP-support in jQuery. Of course it can be anything, but that's hardly helpful, is it?

Answer (score -3):

You read the API documentation for the web service that you are trying to access.