# Can't get jQuery ajax work

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to jQuery, and it really cool, but I can't get the basic ajax work, there's no error in the console ,so I don't know where goes wrong:

```
getJSON function version:

   $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://pollview:8888/js/example.json', function(data){
            for(var element in data){
                console.log(data[element]);
            }
        });

    });
```

then the basic ajax version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://pollview:8888/js/example.json'
    }).done(function(data){
        alert('successful');
    });
});
```

---

I've put the chrome network console here, it seems like the example.json file has been loaded, but the event haven't been triggered, I don't know why

[image]

I get me stuck, any idea?

Comment: Is the page containing the above code being served from `pollview:8888`?

Comment: Can you inspect with Chrome Developer Tools the Network tab and check what is the request response headers and body?

Comment: as @techfoobar points out, if you are serving this from a different location than `pollview:8888`, you will have issues with 'same origin'.

Comment: have you tried using Developer Tools to see what is actually being sent/returned?

Comment: @davehale23 I've tested this in the testing server, so it shouldn't be any cross domain issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wyBqk/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/UGQYT/ (with data returned)

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

- Please check your `json` url.

Also whack in the the `error:` which will tell you if you have error in data coming in. `:)`

Rest this should help you to nail your issue `:)`

**code**

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function() {
        alert("success");
    }).success(function() {
        alert("second success");
    }).error(function() {
        alert("error");
    }).complete(function() {
        alert("complete");
    });

});​
```

Comment: Are you doing a cross domain request. what do the tags do here in the url:  ?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=? How are they related to the json file. Just wish to know. If I replace http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne with another url what changes I will have to make it to work for other json feeds.

Comment: @Mike Hey Bruv, Tags just get the public pictures from flicker, like cats, dogs etc i.e. just wanted to get the sample `.json` url to show if success what will happen, see a working demo in the JQuery site: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON `:)` it uses the same url.

Comment: @tats_init: Thanks Dear. But why i am getting error here. http://jsfiddle.net/wyBqk/3/  Actually here   http://jsfiddle.net/wyBqk/4/

Comment: Hiya @Mike because I reckon nytimes is doing a check of source from where the request is coming from and it fails request, :) same thing will happen if you try to borrow if from tutorial website or NASDAQ site. ':)'

Comment: ' **also** if you copy paste the URL in ur browser it will throw 404 - http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml&jsoncallback=? For this,So it's not valid json URL. :))

Comment: @tata_init; I have heard the the server should support jsonp to make cross domain requests. Is ny times not supporting jsonp, what is the way to check if a server supports jsonp format. sorry if I am talking non sense. I dont know much about json/jsonp

Comment: @Mike all good man, no worries :) no question is bad question, check this one out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467366/how-do-i-know-if-a-server-has-jsonp-turned-on

Comment: @Tats_innit I've update the question with screenshot of chrome console

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting `dataType:'json'`?

---

anyway, your code worked fine for me.

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/WuT6y/

Answer (score 0):

How stupid I am, I made 2 mistakes:

1. `$('document')` instead of `$(document)`
2. The Json file is not valid, after use codeigniter's output method I made the valid file, it seems to me, only the blank space eliminated.

There's no Cross domain issue in my case