# Get prayer time JSON data using JQUERY and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I want to READ JSON data using Jquery ana Ajax from this link

http://praytime.info/getprayertimes.php?lat=31.950001&lon=35.9333&gmt=180&m=3&y=2013&school=0&format=json&callback=?

and this is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

 var strUser ="http://praytime.info/getprayertimes.php?lat=31.950001&lon=35.9333&gmt=180&m=3&y=2013&school=0&format=json&callback=?";

 $.ajax({ 
   url: strUser ,
   dataType: 'jsonp',    
   success: function(data){

        jQuery.each(data, function(){
           alert("yes");

       });                
    }

  });


 });
```

I tried this code with other links , and it's correct, but from the specified link I don't get any out put, can you help me??

Comment: URL is outputting `json` but for cross domain need `jsonp`. Not all API's provide `jsonp` in which case you will need to use a proxy to retrieve data

Comment: `jsonp` != cross-domain `json`. The server needs to understand your request.

Comment: @charlietfl can you turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are trying to access with JSONP doesnot support it. The server will need to return the response as JSON, but also wrap the response in the requested call back. So a way to solve this problem is using a server side proxy, which fetches the response from the specified url and passes it on to your client side js, like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url_to_yourserverside_proxy,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
  }
});
```

where
`url_to_yourserverside_proxy` is a server side file that fetches response from the url specified

Comment: can you please check this link

http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Tripoli,libya=xml&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=d35160acaf083722112707&callback=?

in the url appear that it's return json, and it works well, how can I determine the diffrence?

Comment: @Alaa check this link:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467366/how-do-i-know-if-a-server-has-jsonp-turned-on

Answer (score 1):

URL is outputting `json` but for cross domain need `jsonp`.

Not all API's provide `jsonp`. If cross domain API doesn't provide `jsonp` and isn't `CORS` enabled you will need to use a proxy to retrieve data due to `same origin policy`