# json: Response data not showing up in alert

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am using following ajax to receive data from server.

```
$.get("http://***/umbraco/Api/SomeApi/SignIn",{apiVersion : 1,email:"name@gmail.com", password:"mypassword" },function(data) {
   alert('in');
   alert(data);
}, "jsonp");
```

I could see 200 Ok in inspect element. And i could also see the response text. But i couldn't get data in alert. Both above alerts aren't working.

**EDIT**

I tried the following ajax:

```
 jQuery.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: 'http://***/umbraco/Api/SomeApi/SignIn?apiVersion=1&email=name@gmail.com&password=mypassword&callback=?',  
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function (results) {  
        alert("Success!");  
    },  
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
        alert("error");  
        alert('XMLHttpRequest '+ XMLHttpRequest);
        alert('textStatus '+ textStatus);
        alert('errorThrown '+ errorThrown);
    }  
});
```

Results in:

```
 Status Code: 200 Ok
```

But,

Parse Error is throwing. How can i fix this?

[image]
[image]

Please Help.

Comment: Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`..

Comment: tried it. No luck. Returns an error: Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: To avoid that it's better to use `jsonp`..your previous method and also use `JSON.stringify` while you alert data..

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get u

Comment: Stick with `jsonp` and while you alert data use JSON.stringify..eg:alert(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: ok. got it.Tried it.Still not working. I can't even make an "alert('in');" work inside the success function. That is the problem.

Comment: It would have been much more clearer if you had fiddled the code.

Comment: Sorry! that api works only for perticular domain.

Answer (score 0):

For the service to be called using jsonp, the service has to return jsonp which is actually a javascript code.

If it is a third party service, pls make sure that the service supports jsonp.

Comment: I could see all the values in the network tab of inspect element. But why parse error? Response header says that content-type: application/json. Still i couldn't make it work. Is there any issue with my code?

Comment: @Erma Isabel, from the comments of your question, i can see that you got "Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error once, which means the service is in a different domain. in that case you have to use jsonp only , supplying a callback with the ajax call. To achieve this your server has to support jsonp, it has to return something like callback({json data});. Also you need to define your call back function in javascript. so pls ensure 2 things - whether the server is in different domain, and if it supports jsonp. then use jsonp.

Comment: How do i know it supports jsonp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467366/how-do-i-know-if-a-server-has-jsonp-turned-on refer this post

Comment: When i try that it returns "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error".Does that mean anything?

Comment: did u try accessing it directly from browser?

Comment: can u post the request url u tried and the response you got? did u append callback function to the url and what is the response u got?

Comment: from your response it is obvious that u receive only "true " in response and there is no callback wrapper. so ur service doesnot seem to support jsonp. If you have control over the service you can set the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "*" to over come this.

Comment: How does that possible? I am using the same origin allowed by the server.

Comment: Are you setting the domain to the same origin allowed by the server somewhere? cos from the response i could see that only one origin is allowed..

Comment: yes, i set up my domain as the allowed origin using mongoose.

Comment: but it still returns "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error" when the ajax call happens right? then hope it is something to do with setting domain..

Comment: No, i doesn't, see status code 200 ok. My problem is that, instead of success function, error is triggering. Parse error. If it is "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error", i will not be able to see the response in the inspect element as well.

Comment: ok. Are you sure the data returned is json format? i think problem is with format.JQuery might be throwing error if response couldnot be parsed as JSON. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success

Comment: May be, i am using "dataType: "json" in ajax and in response header it is said that, content-Type : application/json. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes. it makes sense. as a final try, can u remove the datatype:json in ajax call as a final try? second, add  contenttype:"application/json" and dataType:json and check

Comment: When i remove "dataType: "jsonp",", it triggers, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error". When i add "contenttype:"application/json" and dataType:json", then previous issue, parse error.

Comment: So you are saying, there is nothing else to try? Can this be server issue?

Comment: I m pretty sure that it is something to do with dataType/contentType.. btw, why are you still using jsonp if your domain is allowed by the server

Comment: Oopz..sorry my mistake tried, dataType:json. it still triggers, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error"

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query for a similar issue

Comment: Then it is cross origin issue, check if your origin is in the list of allowed origins.