# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement jquery jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using below code to access rest service hosted on another domain.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            success: function(json) {
                alert(json);
            },
            error: function(e) {
               console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
```

I am able to get the data correctly, but I get this error in firebug in mozilla:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>
> {"Hello":"World"}

Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong here? Even though Json data is valid. I tried all the suggestions posted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456146/ajax-call-and-clean-json-but-syntax-error-missing-before-statement) But still I am getting same error.

Comment: the response is not a valid jsonp response.... it should be something like `jsonpCallbackName({"Hello":"World"})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't have control on response, It is hosted by third party. I can only just consume it :(

Comment: Why do you specify `jsonpCallback` and also success function which gets your json ?

Comment: And please, dont set `async: false`. You're locking the browser with no reason.

Comment: `async: false` doesn't work with jsonp request

Comment: @dystroy jsonp does respect async anyway

Comment: "It is hosted by third party" so does it accept jsonp request?

Comment: @A.Wolff, I am not sure. But the main issue is I don't have control on that server side

Comment: @RanveerSinghRajpurohit you just can test it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3467409/1414562  And following your comments i guess it doesn't. So then, you have to proxify it server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's really JSON you ask for, don't set `"jsonp"` as `dataType`, and don't provide a callback :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(json) {
            alert(json);
        },
        error: function(e) {
           console.log(e.message);
        }
});
```

Comment: afaik, `contentType` is only when you're posting to the server, not fetching data from it.

Comment: @Andy Yes . contentType is for sending. datatype is for expectation from server.

Answer (score 0):

the format of JSON and JSONP are slightæy different
JKSONP is a function invocation expression

```
callback({"hellow":"world"});
```

whereas JSON is simply a serialized object

```
{"Hello":"world"}
```

fromyour posting it would seem that the server is returning JSON and not JSONP

So you either need to change the server to reply correctly (The actual callback name is a get parameter to the request). You should do this if you are using the ajax call across domains

If you are not using ajax across domains stick to regular JSON

Comment: But I am using cross domain ajax requests.

Comment: @RanveerSinghRajpurohit in which case you need the server to supply valid JSONP instead of JSON