# submit html form with AJAX and display json response from external api

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cors

I have a very basic form with one input field. I want to submit this form using AJAX and display the response within a div on the page.

Some points.
- The response from the API is JSON datatype.
- The API is not on the same server as the client making the request.

With my current code, i can see the request is being made but I am not getting anything back. I do see a warning in my debug console but I am not sure how to proceed or how to update my code to make it work.

Warning in debug Console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?&host=www.domain.com. This can
>   be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

-- My HTML --

```html
<body>
  <form id="myAjaxRequestForm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Request</legend>
      <p>
        <label for="hostname">Host:</label>
        <input id="hostName" type="text" name="hostName" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Submit" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div id="anotherSection">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Response</legend>
      <div id="ajaxResponse"></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</body>
```

-- My Jquery with AJAX --

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Stops the submit request
  $("#myAjaxRequestForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  //checks for the button click event
  $("#myButton").click(function(e) {

    //get the form data and then serialize that
    dataString = $("#myAjaxRequestForm").serialize();

    //get the form data using another method
    var hostName = $("input#hostName").val();
    dataString = "host=" + hostName;

    //make the AJAX request, dataType is set to json
    //meaning we are expecting JSON data in response from the server
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: "json",

      //if received a response from the server
      success: function(response) {
        $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Server Name:</b> " + response.first + "");
        $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Port:</b> " + response.second + "");
        $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Protocol:</b> " + response.third + "");
      },

    });
  });

});
```

Comment: I updated the datatype to "jsonp", re-ran the api call and got this error in the debug console

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement                                 analyze:1:7

the file 'analyze' belongs to the api server - does this mean it doesn't support jsonp or is there another error in my code somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: means you can not call https:// sites from http:// and most browsers disable this.

Solution:

1) Use **jsonp** instead of **json** for dataType: "json" if it works, all is fine

2) if **jsonp** is not supportted, make one php file in your working directory, access API VIA curl. and echo response as json. and then only call that php from your ajax.

**UPDATE IF JSON FAILS**

I assume you are using php

1. Create a php file called api.php in your directory

   ```
   <?php
   header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
   //create cURL connection
   $curl_connection =curl_init('https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?host='.$_REQUEST['host']);

   ///set options
   curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
   curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
   curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


   //perform our request
   $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
   echo $result;
   //close the connection
   curl_close($curl_connection);


   ?>
   ```
2. Now Make ajax call to api.php from your javascript not https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "yourhost/yourpath/api.php", //change this that suits you
     data: dataString,
     dataType: "json",
     ....
   ```

**Finally populate values like this**

```
    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Server Name:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].serverName+ "");
    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Port:</b> " + response.port+ "");
    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Protocol:</b> " + response.protocol+ "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your first solution.

I updated the datatype to "jsonp", re-ran the api call and got this error in the debug console

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement                                 analyze:1:7

the file 'analyze' belongs to the api server - does this mean it doesn't support jsonp or is there another error in my code somewhere?

Comment: please add following line and let me see your output. console.log(result); on the first line inside success fucntion

Comment: sure, i did that. where do i find the console.log output ?

Comment: F12 for chrome and click console tab

Comment: here it is from chrome:

analyze?&callback=jQuery111003550140524748713_1428300933030&host=www.verisign.com&_=1428300933031:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: i got closer with your suggested api.php solution:

after making a call to api.php - see the div on the html was populated but the values where 'undefined'

Server Name: undefined
Port: undefined
Protocol: undefined

in my code I have this but i have a feeling its wrong?

$("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Server Name:</b> " + response.first + "");

what is the correct parameter i should be using here instead of 'response.first' ?

Comment: Yes i have updated how you shoud update div and curl part in php so update once

Comment: works perfectly with that. I tried adding a few more lines to catch more data from the api response but I got 'undefined' on those...

response.grade and response.ipAddress

I followed your example but trying to understand why they didnt work.. the case sensativity is exactly as how it is in the api response..

Comment: all good.. as the data was after the first endpoint i had to add in: endpoints[0] so it looks like this:

response.endpoints[0].grade

thanks for your assistance Sagar! immensely appreciated!!

Comment: please see this image http://prntscr.com/6q622m and do as your needs. your upvote and accepted answer will be appreciated

Comment: sorry, i don't have enough reputation to up vote.

I have one final question and I am happy to open a new thread if required. Basically want to know how to add an if statement on one of the callbacks i.e.

if (response.endpoints[0].statusMessage == "ready") { do stuff.. } but it doesnt seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JSON, you can change the `dataType` attribute to `jsonp`, and the request will complete successfully, ignoring Cross-Origin policy.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?",
  data: dataString,
  dataType: "jsonp",
...
```

Edit: This request successfully circumvents Cross-Origin policy, but it will still cause an `Unexpected Token :` error. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311023/unexpected-token-colon-json-after-jquery-ajaxget) for more information on this error. If you have access to the server from which you're requesting data, add the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*'`. See [here](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) for more information on CORS headers.

Comment: I updated the datatype to "jsonp", re-ran the api call and the CORS warning is gone but now I get this error in the debug console

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement                                 analyze:1:7

the file 'analyze' belongs to the api server - does this mean it doesn't support jsonp or is there another error in my code somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to be a result of the server not supporting JSONP. I determined that from looking on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658674/syntaxerror-missing-before-statement-jquery-jsonp), so it might be a good place to start for answers. Also, [This slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier) is an excellent source of information around getting past Cross-Origin policy.